# How is R.id generated in Android platform?

Tags: java, android

Can I assume that R.id file will be present in every android project?

Or is this specific to certain dev environments?

Comment: They should be part of any android project.

Comment: i would like to detect all widgets from that file and add listeners to them. In order to get notified whenever a widget has been interacted with from the GUI, i would like to log the gui events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It gets autogenerated by the compiler; you can safely assume it will always exist.

Check [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html):

> A project's R.java file is an index into all the resources defined in the file.
>
> You use this class in your source code as a sort of short-hand way to refer to resources you've included in your project.
>
> This is particularly powerful with the code-completion features of IDEs like Eclipse because it lets you quickly and interactively locate the specific reference you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The class `R` is essential to all Android apps and will be automatically generated if your project does not contain errors. So, it's not specific to any build environment other than android itself.

Answer (score 1):

It is generated by the aapt tool. From [android site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html):

> Once you provide a resource in your application (discussed in
>   Providing Resources), you can apply it by referencing its resource ID.
>   All resource IDs are defined in your project's R class, which the aapt
>   tool automatically generates.